# how to get location using async task? android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I am using async task and searching my gps location(using network provider) I am getting a error at `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);`

```
public class SimpleDirect extends MapActivity {
MapView mapView;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_direct_main);
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    initMap();
    new Activity().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == 100) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
class Activity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SimpleDirect.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Mohon tunggu...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        initLocationManager();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

  private void initLocationManager(){
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locListener = new LocationListener() {
             public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
                tampilkanPosisikemap(newLocation);
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0){
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            }
        };
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }

    protected void tampilkanPosisikemap(Location newLocation) {
        List overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        if(overlays.size() > 0) {
            for(Iterator iterator = overlays.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
                GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (newLocation.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (newLocation
                                .getLongitude() * 1E6));

                Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
                icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), icon
                        .getIntrinsicHeight());
                MyItemizedOverlay overlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(icon);
                OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "My Location", null);
                overlay.addItem(item);
                mapView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
                mapView.getController().animateTo(geopoint);
                mapView.postInvalidate();
    }

private void initMap() {
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.simple_direct_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

my logcat:

```
    04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:139)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:137)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:708)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:630)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect.initLocationManager(SimpleDirect.java:128)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect.access$2(SimpleDirect.java:107)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect$Activity.doInBackground(SimpleDirect.java:93)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect$Activity.doInBackground(SimpleDirect.java:1)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-22 20:48:26.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15676):    ... 4 more
04-22 20:48:26.813: E/MapActivity(15676): Couldn't get connection factory client
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676): Activity com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a0aa048 that was originally added here
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a0aa048 that was originally added here
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect$Activity.onPreExecute(SimpleDirect.java:88)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at com.example.simpledirection.SimpleDirect.onCreate(SimpleDirect.java:59)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-22 20:48:27.623: E/WindowManager(15676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You seem to be doing UI stuff on a background thread. You should read more about UI and threads. Also, a logcat is really needed to figure out the error.

Comment: Did you request the appropriate permissions and register the location listener in your manifest?

Comment: i already appropriate permissions at manifest. my code working without async task, and i want use async task to wait while aplication get location

Comment: Have you tried using a handler @ onLocationChanged?

Comment: i just add mmy logcat..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there, David Olsson has mentioned it. You are doing `mapView.postInvalidate();` in `doInBackground`. doInBackground does not allow UI work. For UI work you need to use onPre, or in your case onPost.

The exception says just that

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: ok i get it. but can i show my progress bar while i call initLocationManager() ?? i try to put at pre and post,, there no diference..

Comment: Please try and ask a new question. The only question I have for you is, does my answer deserve a upvote and a mark ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);` inside `AsyncTask` but rather code inside `public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {` should be called on a separate thread.

`requestLocationUpdates` is asynchornous non-blocking call and doesn't require you to add threads. Your `AsyncTask` ends immediately.

Apart from that I would suggest not to have a code structure like this. Notice that every time a location is found, you will start an AsyncTask. You will end up having many started at the same time and memory leaks will also come if you rotate device or finish this `Activity`.

Comment: what should i change to my code in order to prevent memory leak? can u give me suggestion or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me 
You can get location in async

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mw = new Mywidgets(getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);

        try
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait");
            Load_task load_task = new Load_task();
            load_task.execute();

        }catch (Exception e){
            mw.app_log(e.getMessage());
        }



    }

 public class Load_task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
            final String location = bun.getString("location");
            location_arr = location.split(",");

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            List<Address> addresses = new LinkedList<>();
            int c = 0;
            for (String loc : location_arr) {
                //  mw.app_log(loc);
                List<Address> each_addr = null;
                try {
                    each_addr = gc.getFromLocationName(loc, 1);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    mw.app_log("cant get location");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addresses.add(each_addr.get(0));
            }

            lat_long = new ArrayList<LatLng>(addresses.size()); // A list to save the coordinates if they are available
            for (Address a : addresses) {
                if (a.hasLatitude() && a.hasLongitude()) {
                    lat_long.add(new LatLng(a.getLatitude(), a.getLongitude()));
                    mw.app_log("added "+lat_long.toString());
                }else{
                    mw.app_log("not added");
                }
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            mw.app_log(lat_long.toString());
            set_map();

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }


public void set_map(){

 // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

            try {
                progressDialog.hide();


                //addresses.remove(0);


                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                int n = 0;
                for (LatLng lat : lat_long) {

                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(lat).title(location_arr[n++]);

                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.eauction_car_icon_map)).position(lat).snippet(location_arr[n - 1]);
                    mMap.addMarker(marker);
                }

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lat_long.get(2)));
                ;
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lat_long.get(0), 12.0f));
                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        Intent prop_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Property_view.class);
                        int pos = Integer.parseInt(marker.getId().substring(1));
                        //prop_intent.putExtra("location",location[pos]);

                        mw.toast(location_arr[pos]);
                        // startActivity(prop_intent);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("json_obj", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```